# How are wardrobe and makeup table items unlocked?

Tags: sherlock-holmes

I'm playing through *Sherlock Holmes: Crimes and Punishments* for the first time and so far I've solved 3 cases (Black Peter, Riddle of the Rails, and Blood Bath), found every clue, and made the correct conclusion in each case. I also haven't skipped a single mini game, and I'm pretty sure I got every dialog option from everybody.

I thought this would be the key to unlocking vanity items in Sherlock's bedroom, basically just being thorough and finding all the clues, making all the deductions, etc. However, I've only unlocked the top hat (I believe from Riddle of the Rails?), and I still have no glasses and no facial hair. I think I got the Sailor outfit by doing the Black Peter case, but that may have been there from the beginning, I can't remember.

Are these wardrobe and makeup table items unlocked just by progressing through cases, or by doing certain actions, reaching particular conclusions, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it isn't documented anywhere officially, my personal experience with the game suggests that the non-default "vanity items" show up during specific cases that require their use (for a disguise, usually). After finishing the case, that item is unlocked permanently. After finishing the entire game, all vanity items will be unlocked at the start of any subsequent playthroughs.